# Why do I get IllegalAccessError when trying to import a protocol or record from another namespace

Tags: clojure

I have a file in my project where I define a few protocols and records (`defprotocol` and `defrecord`).

I'm trying to use them in a different file/namespace like this:

```
(ns myapp.core
  (:require [myapp.protocols :refer [SomeProtocol]]))
```

This causes an `Execution error (IllegalAccessError) at ....` Does anyone know why?

btw, doing `:refer :all` does work but I don't want to bring in several unneeded symbols into the namespace.

thanks

Comment: Please include an actual full error message, and if at all possible, example input that causes the problem. As it is, you have asked "code that looks sorta like this, but not actually this, causes an error with the following word in it". Not much to go on, you see.

Comment: Is the exception thrown even when you start the REPL from scratch, without any reloads?  Asking because this particular error typically indicates that the Java class at compile time is different than the class at runtime.  In Clojure, often caused by reloading.  In any case, please provide an actual example with the exact steps you took (as @amalloy requests above).